# Best way to track sales/inventory history for a POS system?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

So, I'm writing a POS system, and I want it to be able to keep track of an inventory and generate reports based on past sales.

I'm pretty familiar with database design and that sort of thing, but I'm not quite sure how to approach this particular problem. The first thing I thought was to have tables that track item sales by day, week, month, and year, and then have the program keep track of how much time has elapsed so it knows when to reset these particular records. But now I'm thinking there's got to be a much simpler approach to it than that.

Another thing I thought of doing is to query the sales transaction table based on time stamps, but I'm not sure if that's a step in the right direction either.

I know that there are simpler ways of doing this for things like orders and order history with customers, but what about for the store itself, if they want to track how much product they've sold over the course of a week, month, year, etc? Is it a similar approach? Different? I can't really find anything that speaks to this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with your second thought - create a table for transactions with a timestamp, and use the timestamp to do reports (and partitions if necessary). If you know you will be querying by the timestamp very frequently, you can create an index on it to improve performance.

Whether you are tracking customer orders or store sales shouldn't make a difference in the design unless there is some major requirement difference.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll try that approach and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Will this be a system where store owners are autonomous or will it be a system with a load of POS terminals that report back to a central hub?

If this is for autonomous store owners you have to start worrying about things like backups and data archiving. Stuff that store owners don't really care about. If you look online you'll probably find some cloud providers that do all this POS stuff for store owners.

On the other hand the general design pattern for larger businesses I have seen is as follows:

1. On your POS terminals hold minimum required data that is needed at the POS terminal. Minimal reporting is required at the terminal.
2. Replicate all POS data to a central database server that keeps and merges all different POS terminals. This is your detailed operational reporting. Once data is replicated here it can be deleted from the terminal

Often the store guys aren't too interested in the longer trends but it depends on the business.

Now you can run a report by month or year off the central database server (as can your store owners) and just summarise up to month/year in place. At this point there is no need to create summary tables.

Eventually you'll run into performance issues as data size increases.

The answer to this is not to build summary tables because then your user / reporting system gets complicated because you have to pick the correct table.

The answer is to apply standard performance tuning techniques such as:

- Improving server hardware (Just adding RAM often is the most cost effective)
- Adding Indexes (including indexed views)
- Implementing partitioning
- Consider using cubes for reporting

If this is not sufficient you might then want to consider the overhead of batch jobs that populate summary tables. But again Indexed Views can cover this off to a limited extent without requiring summary tables.

You need to understand data sizes, growth and report requirements before considering any design options such as summary tables.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking more for smaller businesses, like mom-and-pop shops or something like that. So it doesn't need to be that complicated  (yet). As time goes on and the application evolves, I'll probably add more functionality to it. But for now, an "autonomous store owner" approach is more what I'm looking for.

Comment: You might find there are already cloud solutions for that. I typed "POS on the cloud" and there are already plenty of players there. Nowadays cloud is the mom and pop solution because its so simple.